# Need to get Spring to return MySQL View data back to REACT front end

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-mvc, view, axios

I am trying to get my Spring  MySQL backend to return a mutli table VIEW (not a single table) thru AXIOS to my REACT front end.

I am testing my Backend with POSTMAN (http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cpysiteassetview)

I get an error messages from SPRING and a long error message from POSTMAN (below).

I am close, but going wrong somewhere and I hope someone more familiar with this can shed some light and explain where I am going wrong.

Here is the VIEW\MODEL\REPOSITORY\CONTROLLER.

...

```
        CREATE 
            ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
            DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
            SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        VIEW `cpysiteasset` AS
            SELECT 
                `cpymaster`.`cpymasterid` AS `cpymasterid`,
                `cpymaster`.`cpymastercode` AS `cpymastercode`,
                `cpymaster`.`cpymastername` AS `cpymastername`,
                `sitemaster`.`sitemasterid` AS `sitemasterid`,
                `sitemaster`.`sitemastercode` AS `sitemastercode`,
                `sitemaster`.`sitemastername` AS `sitemastername`,
                `assets`.`assetsid` AS `assetsid`,
                `assets`.`assetsidentifier` AS `assetsidentifier`,
                `assets`.`assetsname` AS `assetsname`
            FROM
                ((`cpymaster`
                JOIN `sitemaster` ON = `cpymaster`.`cpymasterid`)))
                JOIN `assets` ON ((`assets`.`sitemaster_sitemasterid` = `sitemaster`.`sitemasterid`)))
            ORDER BY `sitemaster`.`sitemastercode` , `assets`.`assetsidentifier`
        
        //MODEL
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "`cpysiteassetview`")
public class CpySiteAssetView {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private int cpymasterid;
    private String cpymastercode; 
    private String cpymastername;
    private int sitemasterid;
    private String sitemastercode; 
    private String sitemastername; 
    private int assetsid;
    private String assetsidentifier; 
    private String assetsname;
    
    @Column(name = "cpymasterid")
    public int getCpymasterid() {
        return cpymasterid;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "cpymastercode")
    public String getCpymastercode() {
        return cpymastercode;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "cpymastername")
    public String getCpymastername() {
        return cpymastername;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "sitemasterid")
    public int getSitemasterid() {
        return sitemasterid;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "sitemastercode")
    public String getSitemastercode() {
        return sitemastercode;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "sitemastername")
    public String getSitemastername() {
        return sitemastername;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "assetsid")
    public int getAssetsid() {
        return assetsid;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "assetsidentifier")
    public String getAssetsidentifier() {
        return assetsidentifier;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "assetsname")
    public String getAssetsname() {
        return assetsname;
    }
            
}
        
        //Repository
        package net.javaguides.springboot.repository;
        
        import java.util.List;
        import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
        import net.javaguides.springboot.model.CpySiteAssetView;
        
        @Repository
        public interface CpySiteAssetViewRepository1 extends JpaRepository<CpySiteAssetView, Long>{
            public List<CpySiteAssetView> findAll();
        }
        
        //Controller
        package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;
        
        import java.util.List;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
        import net.javaguides.springboot.model.CpySiteAssetView;
        import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.CpySiteAssetViewRepository1;
        
        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
        public class CpySiteAssetViewController {
        
            @Autowired
            private CpySiteAssetViewRepository1 cpySiteAssetViewRepository1;
            
            //get all 
            @GetMapping("/cpysiteassetview")
            public List<CpySiteAssetView> getAllCpySiteAssetView(){
                return cpySiteAssetViewRepository1.findAll();
            }
        
        }
```

...

Error Message from Spring:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'cpysiteass0_.id' in 'field list'

Error Message from Postman (first part):
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(Per

Comment: I see you have answered and debugged the same issue. I hope you can lend a hand here.  
Thank you in advance for your interest.
@Janitha Madushan

Comment: I see you have answered and debugged the same issue. I hope you can lend a hand here.  
Thank you in advance for your interest.
 @José Luis Condori Jara

Comment: I see you have answered and debugged the same issue. I hope you can lend a hand here.  
Thank you in advance for your interest.
@davidxxx

Answer (score 0):

OK..commented out //private long id;
and now it works !!!!!